# How can I design a database system to keep track of customer orders and shipping info

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, schema

I am trying to design a database that would be able to keep track of orders, and tracking information with as little repetition as possible. I own a company that gets products from multiple retailers that send the products to the customers directly. So for each order, there will be multiple products and multiple tracking links.
Here is the design of the db thus far:
[image]

This still is slightly repetitive because each order will have multiple rows in the order details and tracking tables. I was just wondering if there were smarter ways to go about designing this. Is this as normalized as possible?

Thanks

Comment: you do not have to be as normalised as possible. in ancient days computers and hard drives were small so it was a sensible cost-saving strategy. yet normalisation is a trade-off between space and the speed and CPU of the query to reassemble the data. the majority of real-world performance issues are fixed by denormalising the data to have less joins at the expense of space and repetition in the database.

Comment: If each order line item(order_details) could potentially be from a different retailer I would say just add `retailer` and `tracking_no` to `order_details`, with `retailer` being a FK to a retailer table. I'm guessing there is more then one shipper involved, so I would include the shipper als0.

Comment: @simbo1905:  The main goal of normalization is to avoid the possibility of anomalies that can make the data inconsistent. Ans as data consistency is very important normalization is very important. The needed disk space may or may no be reduced in the process of normalization. And the "majority of real-world performance issues" are fixed by proper indexing, not denormalization. Denormalization **can** be used to improve performance but only as a **last resort** and with great care.

Comment: @simbo1905: And CPU speed is relatively unimportant when dealing with relational database. The main break on the hardware side is disk access here. So what you want to do is reduce disk I/O and make the needed I/O as fast as possible mainly by reducing the disks' seek times as low as possible but also by fast buses.

Comment: Hmm, tracking details are related to a particular item in a particular order, is that right? Then I think `tracking_details` should not reference `order` but `order_details`. `(order_id, product_id)` should be a key (or even the primary key) in `order_details` and `(order_id, product_id)` should be a foreign key in `tracking_details` referencing the a fore mentioned key in `order_details`.

Comment: `retailer` should be removed from `products`. Depending on further needs you may want a table linking products with *possible* retailers though. Enforcing that a retailer in `tracking_details` is valid will become a little tricky the though.

Comment: @Dana McDowelle what language are you going to use to implement your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I don't understand from your model are the business rules between `tracking_details` and `order_details`. Your model shows that `tracking_item` and `product` both have a `retailer`. So I might guess that there is a one-to-one relationship between `tracking_details` and `order_details`. It is a very good idea to list out such business rules and draw a diagram that spells them out.

Here is a model in UML notation I did a while ago. From what I can tell if you rename `Contract` to `order` in my diagram is pretty much equivalent to your model. My diagram tries to capture things like the business rules between what is in the things in the order (I called them `LineItem`, you called them `order_details`) and how it is shipped (I called them `Delivery` and you called them `tracking_details`):

[image]

I use the free online tool [umletino](http://www.umletino.com/umletino.html) to draw that UML diagram.

To really understand the business rules you need them to be explicitly spelt out. For example, the business rules of my model are:

1. A contract has many lineitems
2. A contract has many deliveries
3. A delivery to a location contains one or many lineitems
4. A lineitem is a quantity of a given product within a contract
5. A lineitem can only be in zero or one deliveries
6. Altering the lineitems within a contract updates the total cost of a contract

There are some other things in that high-level UML model. The black triangles imply 'aggregation' or 'ownership'. So the diagram indicates that the `Contract` (you called it `order`) controls the life-cycle of the items it owns below it. The implies that if I delete the order I will also delete it's `Deliveries` (you called those `tracking_details`) and it's `LineItems` (you called those `order_details`).

An additional facet of the UML diagram is that it marks some tables as `<<Root Entity>>`. This is a concept that is basically about how not to corrupt your database model. In my model the total cost of the contract/order must equal the sum of the costs of the order_details/lineitems. Yet I could write buggy code that screws things up. I could add or update lineitems/order_details and forget to update the total cost on the order table. The big idea of root entities is that you don't have code that just writes data behind the back of the order. The code that controls the order is responsible for updating the total quality and doing the insert/update/delete of the LineItems/order_details. That single code path ensures that the total quantity of the order always matches the sum of the LineItems/order_details within the database. The `Product` is also marked as a root entity and it might control it's own set of aggregate entities which are not shown on that diagram which is focusing on documenting only Contract/order.

In summary, I don't see any duplication in your model. If I was working on your project what I would like to see alongside the relational model are the business rules and ideas of how to organise code to help avoid corrupting the model or breaking the business rules. I would also like to understand the lifecycle of the things in your model such as aggregation. I encourage you to list out your business rules like I listed out mine above. Then try to draw a diagram (try that free tool at the link above) that captures all of the business rules. We call that a logical model. Then make the physical data model. (Warning: I wouldn't advise going crazy with UML only use enough to capture the key business ideas.)

To implement the physical model I needed one more table than implied by boxes in the UML. I needed a join table between delivery/tracking_details and the lineitems/order_details. That table would capture which delivery/tracking_detail was tracking which things within the order. If you list out the business rules and read through them it helps you uncover such details. My model says that a lineitem/order_detail can only be in one delivery. That business rule cannot be enforce with something like a foreign key constraint. Instead the single code path of my root entity ensure that all of the business rules around orders are checked in one place then unit tested logic would update all the associated tables. If you are using an OO language then that code would be in your Contract/order class. Other classes representing other root entities such as Product would enforce their own business rules and manage their own tables.

Answer (score 0):

Your data model is reasonable as far as it goes.  However, I do note that `TrackingDetails` and `OrderDetails` are both at the `OrderId`/`ProductId` levels.

That suggests that `TrackingDetails` should really have an `OrderDetailsId` instead of the `OrderId` and `ProductId`.

That said, I don't know if this is reasonable from a business perspective.  `OrderDetails` doesn't have a "quantity", so I don't know if that is an oversight or if multiple products are different rows.  Also, I don't know if a quantity of more than 1 could have split tracking information.  That is, someone orders 100 foos, only 50 are in stock so 50 are shipped today and 50 next week.